# About relative clause

Tags: grammar, relative-clauses

I'm learning English in recent days and I read something made me really confused. The sentence is:

> π[q] is the length of the longest prefix of P that is a proper suffix of Pq.

I see that "that is a proper suffix of Pq" is a relative clause, but I don't understand what the proper suffix of Pq is, is it π[q] or something else?

Comment: It would be good to have the sentence in context; also, a link to it. Based on a search at Google Books, I assume it's from this book: https://books.google.ca/books?id=9KFpSmrCU4cC&pg=PA595&dq=%22is%20the%20length%20of%20the%20longest%20prefix%20of%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=cKENVerFFoL4gwThtIDQCw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22is%20the%20length%20of%20the%20longest%20prefix%20of%22&f=false Please confirm.

Comment: @MariusHancu Thank you for your comment! Here is the link:http://www.imada.sdu.dk/~asp/KMP.pdf 
The sentence is in the second paragraph of the Introduction section.

Comment: First understand that that's not "English", it's math-speak, which is indecipherable by mere mortals.

Answer (score 1):

The referent for the relative clause "that is a proper suffix of Pq" is: "...the longest prefix of P"

...of the (longest prefix of p) <-- (that is a proper suffix of Pq)

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I checked a book named "COBUILD English Grammar (Collins COBUILD Grammar)", it says relative clauses reference to the nouns immediately before it. So according to this book, the referenced noun should be "P", what do you think of it?